# Content-Length: 0 with OWIN

Tags: owin, katana

What is the correct way to handle `Content-Length` when writing body content in an Owin middleware?

Currently we're using

```
context.Response.Write(data); // data is a string.
```

In most cases it works, but in some (IIS host on Win 2012 R2) the `Content-Length` gets a value of 0.

I thought that setting the `Content-Length` header, or the option to use `Transfer-Encoding: chuncked` was up to the host to handle, but it looks like I'm missing something.

**What is the correct way to handle the `Content-Length` when writing body content to an OWIN Response stream?**

We've also discussed the bug in a [github issue](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/295).

Comment: It is primarily a host concern. The application may choose to set content-length if it knows exactly what it will be, but otherwise the app should let the server choose to set content-length or chunked.

Comment: It's not clear what would cause content-length to be set to 0. Perhaps there's an exception after the write and the response gets reset? But in that case you should be getting a 500. Try running it under the debugger and see if there are any first chance exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is primarily a host concern. The application may choose to set content-length if it knows exactly what it will be, but otherwise the app should let the server choose to set content-length or chunked.